# Entity Framework Query using Contains with mulitple options

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using entity framework to return a list of people where the forename contains text in a string array.

Let's say:

```
string[] search = new string[] { "bert", "rob" };
```

and query

```
dataContext.People.Where(w => search.Any(a => w.Forename.Contains(a)));
```

This compiles and works BUT the process is actually calling all records from the database and then performing my where clause on the returned data. This makes sense.

Is there a way to rewrite the query so the where clause is generated in SQL?

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068939/join-table-with-collection-entityframework may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that dataContext.People is an `IQueryable` from the `DbSet` and that there is no materialization instruction involved such as `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()`.

the answer is here: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

in your case:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<People>();

foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Forename.Contains (temp));
}
dataContext.People.Where (predicate);
```

Comment: How does this force EF to limit the results by the WHERE clause BEFORE the records are fetched from the database?

Comment: because this works on an IQueryable, and this wil be translated to raw sql before hiting the db. This is why PredicateBuilder was created.

Comment: Small tweak for the entity core but worked a treat, thanks

Comment: This is golden! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) and perform and actual SQL query.

```
dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<People>("SELECT Forename, Lastname FROM myTable WHERE Forename LIKE '%bert%' or Forename LIKE '%rob%'");
```

Comment: now we can talk about using **not parametrized** sql query in an application **using an ORM allowing precompiled queries** :) ...

Comment: @tschmit007 so you're saying EF 5 should not have introduced SqlQuery?

Comment: In my humble opinion, yes, they shouldn't. That said I use it from time to time. But in this case there was an other way.