# Update IQueryable result before using as join in next query

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I need to use Linq to Entity Framework to query a LOCATION table to get the record of the location code with the MAX effective date, then use that result as a join in the next query. 
I BELIEVE I need to do convert before the IQueryable is used, because I have that last clause in the second query where I want to exclude records where the FLOOR code is in the excludedSchools list. That excludedSchools list will have the newLocationCode in it.
So, I need to update the values in the IQueryable result before I use it. Can I do this?  Here is my code:

```
using (var db = new TheContext())  
{
    IQueryable<LocationTable> locatinWithMaxEffDate =
        (from lc in db.LocationTable
            where lc.EFF_STATUS == "A" && lc.EFFDT <= DateTime.Now
            group lc by lc.LOCATION into g
            select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.EFFDT).FirstOrDefault()
        );

    foreach (var location in locatinWithMaxEffDate.ToList())
    {
        string newLocationCode;
        if(codeMappingDictionary.TryGetValue(location.FLOOR, out newLocationCode))
        {
            // how do I update locatinWithMaxEffDate FLOOR value 
            // with newLocationCode so it works in the query below?
            location.FLOOR = newLocationCode;
        }
    }

    var query =
        (from fim in db.PS_PPS_FIM_EE_DATA
            join mloc in locatinWithMaxEffDate on fim.LOCATION equals mloc.LOCATION 
         where
             fim.EMPL_STATUS == PsPpsFimEeData.EmployeeStatusValues.Active
             && fim.AUTO_UPDATE == PsPpsFimEeData.AutoUpdateValues.Enabled
             && includeJobCodes.Contains(fim.JOBCODE)
             && !excludedSchools.Contains(mloc.FLOOR)
         select new PpsAdministratorResult
         {
            SchoolId           = mloc.FLOOR,
            Login              = fim.OPRID,
            EmployeeId         = fim.EMPLID,
}
```

With the code above, the locatinWithMaxEffDate does not have the updated FLOOR values. I can see why this is, but can't seem to fix it.
So far, I have tried introducing another list to ADD() the new location record to, then casting that as an IQueryable, but I get an error about primitive vs concrete types.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the query logic as pseudocode (or even better, as actual SQL)? You might also want to use the LINQ methods rather than the query syntax, just to make it a bit more obvious what you're doing (both for yourself, and for us).

If you could also post any errors you've received that would also help.

Comment: "I can see why this is, but can't seem to fix it"  why do you think it is?

Comment: Have you tried called `db.SaveChanges()` before the second query? If you want your query to be translated into a DB SQL query you'll have to do this. If you're happy for it to be done in memory, then you'll need to assign locatinWithMaxEffDate.ToList() to a variable and do the query on that.

Comment: I suspect the 2nd query isn't using the local IQueryable. I'm thinking I should update the FLOOR value within the first query then.

Comment: Is this really LINQ to SQL or EF?

Comment: What do you mean the "local" `IQueryable` - `IQueryable` just represents the logic of the query you want to do, it doesn't hold data unless you convert it to a collection (e.g. using .ToList()).  As I said, if you want the second query to run against the in-memory data, you'll need to perform it against that list rather than the original `IQueryable`.

Comment: Oops, indeed - Entity Framewrok. I don't think I can edit yet.

Comment: @DylanNicholson That's true, but the complication is that EF does not support joining `IQueryable` with in memory collection.

Comment: Since what you are asking is not directly possible, and there are some EF implied limitations, in order to see if there is a solution at all, I need to know if `mloc` is used for something else than filtering (because you didn't include the `select` part of the query).

Comment: Yes, mloc is used in the select:                          select new PpsAdministratorResult
                         {
                             SchoolId           = mloc.FLOOR,

Comment: Ivan I think EF Core may be able to support it, but at any rate, you can always just pull `db.PS_PPS_FIM_EE_DATA` into a local list too.  The `SaveChanges()` option is probably simplest if the OP is expecting/happy for the DB to be updated.

Comment: Cannot update the database. I suppose a better title for the questions is: How can I use a list of objects as a join in a linq to EF query?

Comment: Which brings me to this post- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068939/join-table-with-collection-entityframework  I have not read through it yet, but it appears it may have the education I need.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make things easier on myself. Since both sets of data are very small (fewer than 1000 records each) I call take the entire set of data as an annonymous type:

```
using (var db = new TheContext())  
{
    IQueryable<LocationTable> locatinWithMaxEffDate =
        (from lc in db.LocationTable
            where lc.EFF_STATUS == "A" && lc.EFFDT <= DateTime.Now
            group lc by lc.LOCATION into g
            select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.EFFDT).FirstOrDefault()
        );
    var query =
        (from fim in db.PS_PPS_FIM_EE_DATA
            join mloc in locatinWithMaxEffDate on fim.LOCATION equals mloc.LOCATION 
         where
             fim.EMPL_STATUS == PsPpsFimEeData.EmployeeStatusValues.Active
             && fim.AUTO_UPDATE == PsPpsFimEeData.AutoUpdateValues.Enabled
             && includeJobCodes.Contains(fim.JOBCODE)
         select new PpsAdministratorResult
         {
            SchoolId           = mloc.FLOOR,
            Login              = fim.OPRID,
            EmployeeId         = fim.EMPLID,
         }  
}
```

Then, just work with the two objects:

```
List<PpsAdministratorResult> administratorList = new List<PpsAdministratorResult>();
foreach (var location in query.ToList())
{
    string newLocationCode;
    if(schoolCodeMappings.TryGetValue(location.SchoolId, out newLocationCode)) // && newLocationCode.Contains(location.LOCATION))
    {
        location.SchoolId = newLocationCode;
    }
    if( !excludedSchools.Contains(location.SchoolId) )
    {
        administratorList.Add(location);
    }
}
```

Now, I have the list I want.